# The raw query in django 1.5 doesn't work with order by desc

Tags: django, sql-order-by, models

```
from project.models import Employees
sorting_field = 'name'
emps = Employees.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM employees where deleted=0 order by %s desc limit 5', [sorting_field])
```

**This doesn't get the order of records in descending order.**

Comment: It have to work. Could you include a sample output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Providing the value of `order by %s` via the `param` argument to `.raw()` won't work because all the params are escaped by the database backend. Therefore you'll end up with a query like `order by 'name'` (note the quotes) which won't work.

Alternatively, you could use string formatting ([which the Django docs strongly and rightely so advise against](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/sql/#passing-parameters-into-raw)) but if you don't use it to put user generated input into the query, you should be fine:

```
if condition:
    sort_field = 'name'
else:
    sort_field = 'id'

query = 'SELECT * FROM employees WHERE deleted = 0 ORDER BY {} DESC LIMIT 5'
params = {…}  # other parameters that need regular escaping
emps = Employees.objects.raw(query.format(sort_field), params)
```

Answer (score 0):

`order_by` is only method of `QuerySet` object, but not `RawQuerySet`. This one of limitation of uwsing Raw obeject in django orm

Comment: I am not inquiring about any object method here. I am mentioning about a simple mysql raw query having order by being executed which doesn't work as it should. The object oriented way utilizing the order_by method works but not the raw query.

Answer (score -1):

Why did you use raw query for so simple task?
Try this:

```
Employees.objects.filter(deleted=0).order_by('-name')[:5]
```

Comment: Help regarding the question is appreciated. No alternate way required. I am well aware when to use a raw query and when not to. My query is bit more complex utilizing joins. Please try to use raw query and see if the output is same as the above. Question is not whether I can do it the object oriented way or utilize a raw query but whether the order by in the raw query functions as it should.